# Active radio button with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, select, radio-button

I used all of the helpful answers on this site to try to build a jquery script to select radio buttons, but for some reason they don't work.  Am I doing something wrong?  For the sake of simplicity I've started back from square one.

I've attached the format that the php-generated form produces below.  I tried multiple browsers, but was unable to get any button to select anything.  Is there some complexity I'm not taking into account?  The page is a .php page, and the form is generated in php.

Sorry for the basic question -- any help would be greatly appreciated.  Not sure if it's relevant, but I want these buttons to work on mobile as well as various browsers.

Form Code:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="submit.php" name="form">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2"></div>
            <div class="span8">
                <label class = "control-label" for="input1"> foreign policy </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="1_l" value="1_l"> Liberal</label>
                    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="1_m" value="1_m"> Moderate</label>
                    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="1_c" value="1_c"> Conservative</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2"></div>
            <div class="span8">
                <br>
                <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-large">Generate</button></center>
            </div>
            <div class="span2"></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('button').click(
function() {
    $('#1_l').attr('checked', true);
}
);
```

Comment: What's your jQuery script look like?

Comment: One thing I'm noticing initially... ID's should generally begin with a letter, not a number.  The ID's for your radio inputs all start with the number 1.  If nothing else, I'd at least update those so the first character is a letter.  May not be the cause of your problem, but I have occasionally run into issues relating to that rule in the past.

Comment: That is true in HTML 4.0 ,, but from HTML5 onwards , id's can start with numbers

Comment: @asparagus in what *way* does it not work?  What happens?  What do you expect?

Comment: First, I'd use a DOM element that is NOT a submit button to test.  You may well be successfully setting the check, submitting the form, and then getting back a fresh page with the item unchecked again.

Second, you can try using click() instead of attr()

Comment: When I click the button, it should be changing one of the radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to only bind the handler after the DOM has been loaded:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#1_l').attr('checked', true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ":checked" selector in jQuery to select the checked input, otherwise you only get the first one.

```
$(function () {

    $('button.btn').click(function () {
        var $box = $('.checkbox input:checked');
        if ($box.length > 0)
            alert($box.val());
    });

});​
```

Comment: HTML only permits you to select one radio button in a radio button group. Therefore you only get one result in the jQuery "array" object. If it where check boxes you could use the :first or .first() selectors to only select one (the first) of the checked input controls.

Comment: right i get the difference .... my point was that the OP gave radio button not checkoxes

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i see  you have a div that was not closed i closed it

I changes the button type to button rather than submit so i could see it work and all was good

[See my working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hacjx/2/)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action="submit.php" name="form">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2"></div>
            <div class="span8">
                <label class = "control-label" for="input1"> foreign policy </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="1_l" value="1_l"> Liberal</label>
                    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="1_m" value="1_m"> Moderate</label>
                    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="radio" name="group1" id="1_c" value="1_c"> Conservative</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2"></div>
            <div class="span8">
                <br>
                <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-large">Generate</button></center>
            </div>
            <div class="span2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>​
```

and here is the jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#1_l').attr('checked', true);
    });​
}
```

Comment: For some reason I put this in and it still doesn't seem to work.  Do you know why the jQuery may not be working?

Comment: How would you insert the jquery script into the page?

Comment: edited to include jQuery function. make sure your loading jQuery !